# $k(R(x),R(x+1)) = k(x)$ for a non-constant rational function $R(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $k$ a field. It is known ([Lüroth's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%BCroth%27s_theorem)) that every subfield of $k(x)$ is of the form $k(\phi(x))$.

We expect that if we take two random non-constant fractions $R(x)$, and $S(x)$ that they generate the field $k(x)$ ( random -- a suggestive term). One can check that in concrete examples using Gröbner bases (elimination). It is definitely so if the degrees of $R(x)$ and $S(x)$ are relatively prime ( the degree of a fraction is the largest of the degrees of the numerator and denominator, equals the cardinality of a generic fibre of the map $x\mapsto R(x)$. Note that the degree of the composition is the product of the degrees).

From now one, $k$ is of characteristic $0$.

I am pretty convinced that given a non-constant fraction $R(x)$, the fraction $R(x)$, $R(x+1)$ generate the whole field of rational fractions.

1. Why do I care about that:  say we have a sequence $a_n \colon n\mapsto R(n)$ where $R(x) \in \mathbb{C}(x)$.  The above implies for instance that the sequence $a_n$ satisfies a rational recurrence of order $2$

$$a_{n+2} = T(a_n, a_{n+1})$$

for all $n\ge 0$.  Note that if $R$ is a polynomial of degree $m$ then the  sequence $a_n = P(n)$ satisfies a linear recurrence of order $m+1$.  But ( perhaps surprising), it will satisfy a rational recurrence of order $2$.

2. How the proof might work.  Assume the contrary, that is both $R(x)$ and $R(x+1)$ are functions of a fraction $\phi(x)$ of degree $> 1$

$$R(x) = U(\phi(x)) \\
R(x+1) = V(\phi(x))$$

We get $U(\phi(x+1)) = V(\phi(x))$.  Let's try to get a contradiction.

Hand-wave approach: the function on RHS is constant on the fibres of $\phi(x))$, while the one on LHS is constant on the translates of the fibres of $\phi$ by $1$.  If $\deg \phi(x) > 1$, we "get" a contradiction

We can prove the impossibility of some particular cases of the above. For instance, we cannot have

$$\phi(x+1) = V(\phi(x)$$

if $\deg \phi> 1$. Indeed, on RHS we need $\deg V = 1$, but then $V$ is a Mobius transform, so conjugate either to a dilation or a translation.  Dilation gets eliminated, and translation means in the end $\phi$ of degree $1$.

Note also that the fact about $R(x)$ is certainly true if $R(x)$ is a polynomial.  Indeed, $R(x+1) - R(x)$ has degree relatively prime to $\deg R(x)$.

This method works to show the statement in explicit cases: if the degrees of $R(x)$ and $R(x+1) - R(x)$  ( or other combinations) are relatively prime, the statement follows.